# How to remove a user from all rosters in Ejabberd

Tags: command-line, xmpp, ejabberd, rostering

I want to delete a chat account and at the same time :

1. Delete his roster
2. Delete him from all of his friends rosters

How can i do this?

I have tried the various options of ejabberdctl. I can unregister a user, and even purge his roster, but I cant find a way to remove him from other rosters.

PS : All my users are currently on one server/host

Answer (score 0):

If you save the roster data in mnesia (`mod_roster`) and not in an external database (`mod_roster_odbc`), then [`mod_admin_extra:delete_rosteritem/4`](http://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/mod_admin_extra/trunk/src/mod_admin_extra.erl) might help you to delete the user's roster. Otherwise you will have to use odbc_queries functionality.

If the user's contacts are your users as well (no s2s connections allowed), then you might use delete_rosteritem with swapped arguments, or use mnesia/odbc hackery. In a federated setup you will not have access to the contact's roster, but you can probably send his server both, an presence unsubscribe and a presence unsubscribed stanza. See [RFC 3921](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html) or ask for detail.

Unfortunately, I do not know a ready-to-use solution, but might come up with one in the following weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually deleting a user will unsubscribe them from all the local user's rosters, as well as send remote users unsubscribe requests through the server-to-server component.  You may want to look at [ad-hoc commands](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0050.html), which [ejabberd supports](http://www.ejabberd.im/protocols).  This way you can script a tool to do it from the command line, which is what it looks like you want from your question tags.

The web admin UI may be a popular place to do it.  I know that is where I've done it with openfire.